# React Native - Common place to do Access Token validation

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a react native app in which I am using Stack navigator. Within the screens I do a few Rest API calls to fetch data.

The Rest API are having Token authentication, which I already saved using AsyncStorage, Access token is valid only for 10 hrs if there is any user action after 10 hrs the user needs to be logged of and redirected to login screen.

I make API calls from ComponentDidMount() , so I have an idea of how to redirect the user to login is token is expired for ex:-

```
   ComponentDidMount()
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
        debugger;
        if (accessToken === null) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
        }
    }
```

But If were to do this kind of check at whole app level, how Can I do it without repeating this piece of code everywhere?

Comment: Can you just put your function at top level entry point of your app so when your app loads it runs this function like index.js or app.js

Comment: @Anthony, can you point me to an example please

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what your app.js looks like but what you can do in react native with the react navigation checkout the basic example I have provided below on how you could create a function and navigate at the top level

App.js

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Auth: LoginScreen,
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {


   async ComponentDidMount()
    {
        let accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
        debugger;
        if (accessToken === null) {
          NavigationService.navigate("Auth");
        }
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

NavigationService.js

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

you can checkout this link 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html